# Adding a prefix to different log levels

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to change the default behaviour of the logging module so that it adds a prefix string to each log level.

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(message)s', filename='output.log', filemode='w')
console = logging.StreamHandler()
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console) # add the handler to the root logger

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

log.info("this is an info")
log.error("this is an error")
log.warning("this is a warning")
```

I want

```
log.error("this is an error")
```

to print:

```
Error: this is an error
```

Or, the following line,

```
log.warning("this is a warning")
```

to print:

```
Warning: this is a warning
```

Error prefix in red and warning prefix in yellow.
Is there any non-hacky way to do this?